# javascript to zoom images

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I cant seem to get this to work.  I'm trying to convert a javascript bookmarklet into a javascript onclick function to zoom in on images in the page.

The bookmarklet is as follows...

```
javascript:(function(){ function zoomImage(image, amt) { if(image.initialHeight == null) { /* avoid accumulating integer-rounding error */ image.initialHeight=image.height; image.initialWidth=image.width; image.scalingFactor=1; } image.scalingFactor*=amt; image.width=image.scalingFactor*image.initialWidth; image.height=image.scalingFactor*image.initialHeight; } var i,L=document.images.length; for (i=0;i<L;++i) zoomImage(document.images[i], 2); if (!L) alert("This page contains no images."); })();
```

But this is what I have so far but is not working properly...

The JS:

```
(function vbZoom() {
    function zoomImage(image, amt) {
        if (image.initialHeight == null) {
            image.initialHeight = image.height;
            image.initialWidth = image.width;
            image.scalingFactor = 1;
        }
        image.scalingFactor *= amt;
        image.width = image.scalingFactor * image.initialWidth;
        image.height = image.scalingFactor * image.initialHeight;
    }
    var i, L = document.images.length;
    for (i = 0; i < L; ++i) zoomImage(document.images[i], 2);
    if (!L) alert("This page contains no images.");
})();
```

The Link: (from an image)

```
<img id="vZoomIn" onclick="vbZoom()">
```

Please help, anyone.

EDIT:  I should note... it partially works.  What it currently does is makes images on the page twice as big upon loading but then the button does nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the function in those brackets means it's called immediately and not available outside the brackets, known as [Immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), change it to

```
function vbZoom() {
    function zoomImage(image, amt) {
        if (image.initialHeight == null) {
            image.initialHeight = image.height;
            image.initialWidth = image.width;
            image.scalingFactor = 1;
        }
        image.scalingFactor *= amt;
        image.width = image.scalingFactor * image.initialWidth;
        image.height = image.scalingFactor * image.initialHeight;
    }
    var i, L = document.images.length;
    for (i = 0; i < L; ++i) zoomImage(document.images[i], 2);
    if (!L) alert("This page contains no images.");
}
```

Actually there's a lot that should probably be changed in the code however that should at least work and be available to the rest of the page and not automatically called.

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything at all.  What am I missing?  Do I have the link right?

Comment: I've expanded the code, is this what you are now doing?

Comment: yes it is.  Could it have something to do with the fact that this is a javascript injection whereas I have the html in a javascript innerHTML like so...  vbar.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.versitek.com/" target="_blank"><img src="' + versitekURL + '"></a><img id="vZoomIn" onclick="vbZoom();">';

Comment: Can you put a minimal complete html page up that shows the problem, but is as small as possible? A site like http://jsbin.com/ is a good place to use.

Comment: Several things, you left a chrome.extension reference in, body has no children in the example and jsfiddle adds javascript in a bad way, here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/Qj6Wp/2/

Comment: The chrome extension reference is supposed to be there because that is what I am creating.  I can not create the standard html elements but simply have to inject them into the body of the page itself using the javascript.  Are there any alternatives?  The chrome extension reference is what defines that img url that is relative to the extension path because without it there, the page will try to look for the image relative to the path of the website that the user is on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fancybox

1. use Jquery then use fancybox css & js
2. use the fancy box html given below, it help to zoom your image as much you want.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.css">

   <a class="hidden-md hidden-lg" href="https://bdtender.com/tenderimage/Feb04/Feb04_BT040221-2A.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="My caption">
    <img src="https://bdtender.com/tenderimage/Feb04/Feb04_BT040221-2A.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto;" alt="" />
   </a>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.js"> 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
 
}

modal.onclick = function() {
    img01.className += " out";
    setTimeout(function() {
       modal.style.display = "none";
       img01.className = "modal-content";
     }, 400);
    
 }
```

```css
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 75%;
    //max-width: 75%;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.out {
  animation-name: zoom-out;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(2)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0.4)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom-out {
    from {transform:scale(1)}
    to {transform:scale(0)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/journey_start_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="500" height="300">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>
```